# How to Check Array for 3 Numbers that Add to a Specific value in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Alright guys, I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and have not been able to get past it. This is for Java. I'd appreciate any help at this point. Here are the details: **Please note, we must do this in O(n) running time. We are given an array of numbers and must go through it to determine if there are any 3 numbers that sum to a specific number. HOWEVER, we are allowed to reuse any number in the array up to 3 times because we need a total of 3 numbers. We also have to output which 3 numbers gave the sum. Returning true or false.**

Below is what I've got:

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: You are using `Arrays.sort` - this precludes an `O(n)` algorithm as `sort` must by its nature be `> O(n)`.

Comment: If it was 2 numbers it could be done in O(n) by using a HashSet or similar structure with O(1) access and subtraction, but it's 3, so the best you can possibly get is O(n^2). If it was 4 numbers, best case complexity would be O(n^3) and so on...Of course this is assuming that there are no restrictions on the n numbers and that they are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for loop inside of a for loop inside of a for loop. This is for school, so I wont give you the code, but I'll give you the pseudo.

Edit: missed the O(n) part, sorry. This way should work.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 int[] test = {1,8,2,3,11,4};
 System.out.println(threeSumTo(test, 6));
 }

//check if 3 numbs in an array add up to int x
public static boolean threeSumTo(int[] array, int x) 
{
//loop through the array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    boolean result = twoSumTo(array, x - array[i], i);
    if (result) {
        return result;
    }
}
return false;
}

private static boolean twoSumTo(int[] array, int x, int low) {
int high = array.length - 1;
while (low < high) {
    if (array[low] + array[high] == x) {
        return true;
    }
    if (array[low] + array[high] > x) {
        high--;
    } else {
        low++;
    }
}
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: but this has a O(n^3) running time and I need something that has O(n) or even O(n^2log n).

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. Now, the first boolean loops through each number, and the second loops through different combinations with the numbers. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: it does work, but it takes very very long, so I still don't think it's O(n) unfortunately :(

Comment: So in other words, can this be made faster?

Comment: one last thing, is there any way we can print out the numbers that were used to get the sum?

Comment: I found this on the interwebs, it should help: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-triplet-that-sum-to-a-given-value/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a variation of the [3SUM problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) and should obey the same restrictions.

Computing the 3SUM problem in less than O(n^2) is still a unsvoled problem.

Did your teacher ask a trick question or is that some kind of competition?

Comment: Well AceOfBlades suggestion at least computes near O(n^2). Perhabs he was hoping someone solves this unsolved question with a great idea :D he probably did not want his students to ask on stackoverflow though^^

Comment: It simply got to the point where I was too curious man! I couldn't get my head around how this could be O(n) and I guess it can't...lol

Comment: shouldn't you accept another answer as AceOfBlades answer clearly does not solve your question and could be misleading in future references?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a 3 sum problem and solving this problem in O(N) is impossible till now. The best you can do is O(N^2).

Check [this article](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/leetcode-3sum-closest-java/) out.